# Docker containers on different stacks and networks communicationg each other

Tags: docker, docker-network, docker-stack, portainer

in my microservices architecture application I'd like to add Sleuth and Zipkin server (image from Docker Hub). Everything works fine locally - each microservice sends data to Zipkin server. The problem is more complicated when I deployed all microservices on the server  -Zipkin Web UI is empty - no traces.

In application.properties we can explicitly set the url to the Zipkin server:
spring.zipkin.base-url: http://10.0.44.1:9411/

- I'm using Portainer
- all my microservices are in stack X in Network X1
- Zipkin is in stack Y, in Network Y1.

I thought that all containers can communicate each other in different stacks/networks but it's not true.
What should I do to publish my Zipkin server/container to be availabe for all containers from all stacks/networks?

Is there a possibility to do this using Portainer?

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

You can connect your existing container to another network

```
docker network connect [OPTIONS] NETWORK CONTAINER
```

Comment: And what URL to the ZPikin server should I set? spring.zipkin.base-url: http://myUrl:9411/zipkin/ ??? Or nothing - by default?